# What's the correct way to add a collection of file locations to a List?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

What the equivalent code to build a List of files? I'm creating an array like this.

```
arctopithecusImages = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg");
```

I tried this to build my List, but it's not working. What's the correct way to do this?

```
List<FilePath> arctopithecusImageList = new List<FilePath>();
arctopithecusImageList.Add(Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg"));
```

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/16433/get-list-of-all-files-in-a-directory.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple as that:

```
Directory.GetFiles( [...] ).ToList()
```

Comment: Cool, This is what I've got now: `Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg").ToList(arctopithecusImageList);`  error says ToList takes 2 arguments - what's the second one?

Comment: [refer here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) ... in your case, just do `List<FilePath> arctopithecusImageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg").ToList();`